# Magento 2.2.4 Attribute "manufacturer" only showing in simple product, not in other product types

Tags: magento2, admin, attributes, products

I've created attribute **manufacturer**. It only shows when I add **simple product**, but when I whant to add other type of product, attribute is not showing.

Comment: Can you please make sure that, the attribute type of simple products is same as other products, also please try to check after reindexing

Comment: How can I do that? 
Thanks for your answer.

Comment: go to Stores >> Attribute set and check if multiple set is available or not ?

Comment: I have Default attribute set. Manufacturer attribute is added to default set, but it only shows when I add simple product.

Comment: did you run re-indexing after create attribute ?

Comment: Yes, i did run re-indexing, but nothing happend. I read every post regarding this problem, but I couldn't find any solution. All other attributes that I made are visible on all product types.

Comment: for example which product type you are creating ?

Answer (score 3):

Since this just happened out of the blue to me - after things working fine for months:

In the table `catalog_eav_attributes` there is a column called `apply_to`

Back in Magento1 this was visible and editable in admin, but in Magento2 it is not. And it can be changed to limit the product types attributes apply to. If it is a list of product types, only these will display the attribute.

I just looked in the the M2 codebase the default for manufacturer is simple,configurable - no idea why

Also no idea what reset it on my site or made my site suddenly "apply" the restriction, but until recently I could edit manufacturer on all my product types, and suddenly today I could not, so something changed

Making that `apply_to` value NULL fixed my problem (clear cache, reindex, log out of admin etc)